# G a Lie group. What is the map between the trivial bundle and the tangent bundle (to prove they are diffeomorphic)

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle

OK, so this is a really silly question. But for the life of me I do not understand how the map $\Phi$ is defined in the proof presented in the first response to the following question: [Let $G$ be a Lie group. Show that there is a diffeomorphism $TG \cong G \times T_e G$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308691/let-g-be-a-lie-group-show-that-there-is-a-diffeomorphism-tg-cong-g-times-t/308798#308798)

All it says is $\Phi(g,X)=(Lg)_∗(X)$; but my understanding is that a Tangent bundle of a manifold $M$ is $TM=\{(x,v)|x\in M, v\in T_x(M)\}$, and I do not see which $x$ and $v$ are targeted in this definition.

Comment: It might help to match the ordered pair notation $(x,v) \in TM$ with the ordered pair notation $(g,X)$ in the formula for $\Phi$: $x=g$ and $v=X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L_g$ the left multiplication by $g$. bu definition, it is a diffeomorphism of $G$ (with inverse $L_{g^{-1}}$). The image by its derivative $L'_g$ of the tangent space at the identity $T_eG$ is therefore the tangent space $T_gG.$
The map $F: G\times T_eG \to TG$ given by $F(g, v)=(g, L'_gv)$ is therefore a diffeomorphism, and in fact an isomorphism of bundles over $G$.

Comment: One might add that the notation $(Lg)_*$ in the question is identical to the notation $L'_g$ of this answer, namely, the linear isomorphism $T_e G \to T_g G$ obtained by differentiating the map $L_g$, which depends continuously and smoothly on $g$.